# Syntax error in Magento when I create an Invoice in the admin

Tags: magento

I'm getting Syntax error, Unexpected T-ENDIF error when I create an invoice in the admin of Magento. I can get round it by pressing the back button in the broswer. Then go and see the generated invoice manually.

So how can I fix this error from displaying?

Here is the error displayed:
[image]

Here is the code for the page that errors:

[image]

Hope someone can help fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

In a first look I'd tell all you need to do is to get rid of the line  in the line 38. The error was actually telling you that.

But most likely you actually deleted one line in your code. Look [this file](https://github.com/webbyfox/mirror-theme/blob/master/template/email/order/items/invoice/default.phtml) on line 32. Yours doesn't have it. You should restore it adding getItemOptions()): ?>.